# How do I view attachments in the default email client?

Tags: pantheon-mail

in the standard email client I do not see attachments, how do I see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on the email so that the preview/viewing pane opens up and then they're just below that.

I made you a helpful graphic:

[image: open attachments]

You can double-click on the attachment and open it in the default client. If you right click on it, your choices are 'open' and 'save'.

After a few tests, they all showed up. If you're unable to see an expected attachment, I'd suspect that it's a malformed email. I was able to send and receive several emails with attachments in short order.

Tested with eOS Here 5.1.7

Comment: Thank you very much :) In a large chain of emails I did not immediately see where the attachment is located :)

Comment: @c0mrad3, it's all good. We all miss stuff. We all sometimes have to hunt around and still can't find what we're looking for. That's why sites like this exist. They exist because there's a whole lot to learn and remember.